# Функция привязанная к кнопке срабатывает только при двойном нажатии

Tags: javascript, html

Повесил на кнопку обработчик, в итоге чтобы он сработал - нужно нажать два раза. Первое нажатие "обводит" кнопку в синий цвет, то есть делает ее как бы активной, и уже потом работает по одному нажатию все как должно.

Если в какое-то место на сайте нажать (не на кнопку) - опять эта "обводка" с кнопки слетает и нужно два раза нажимать.

```
<button id="button" onclick="iTfunction()">ОТКРЫТЬ</a>

<script>
    function iTfunction() {
        if (document.getElementById("imgId").style.display === "none") {
            document.getElementById("imgId").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `<button id="button" onclick="iTfunction()">ОТКРЫТЬ</a>` Открываете как `button`, а закрываете как `a`

Comment: https://playcode.io/ , https://jsfiddle.net/ , https://liveweave.com/ — выберите понравившуюся песочницу и пишите код там. Сразу будут отсекать кучу ошибок по невнимательности.

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил.

Comment: Все равно двойное нажатие требуется.

Comment: `function iTfunction() { document.getElementById("imgId").style.display = "block"; }`  — А кстати, для чего там проверка? Если нет никакого else и оно в любом случае должно его показывать... можно сразу прописать только "показывание" и всё.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function iTfunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("imgId").style.display === "none") {
    document.getElementById("imgId").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#imgId {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<button style="height:24px;" onclick="iTfunction()">ОТКРЫТЬ</button>

<div id="imgId" style="display:none;">123</div>
```

Comment: Или так: https://playcode.io/328365